# How to reinstall a "deinstalled" apt and apt-listchanges on raspbian

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, apt

I'm new to raspberry pi. I have a raspbian os and I accidentally executed this on my terminal:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall apt
```

and it warned me if I wanted to continue should I type "Yes, do as I say!" whereas I did. But then when I tried to run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It did not recognized the apt. "apt is not a command"

And so I tried to find an apt package but I can't find an armhf version of apt. I tried a .deb apt but there are still errors.

I was just trying to install h5py and other tensorflow requirements but failed. Do you know where can I download an armhf apt package and how to install it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: its probably easier to reinstall the whole operating system

Comment: With the version of Python being adjusted to the requirements of raspberry pi and the tensorflow version along with h5py , please find this document which helps install the same on the device . I suggest you boot the system first, uninstall the previous versions and refer to this guide attached.
It gives an exact solution to us and also cautions about the various errors which may come and a workaround to them. [link](https://itnext.io/installing-tensorflow-2-3-0-for-raspberry-pi3-4-debian-buster-11447cb31fc4)